# How to include Angular variable inside different html tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am confused as to why this code doesn't work. I have a controller I am called **sidebar** and this works:

```
<a href="{{sidebar.id}}" >
```

and now my backend programmer wants me to include the **id** in the url that I send info to and yet this will **not** work, how do I get the id number inside the url?

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple data-url="https://domain.com:9999/{{sidebar.id}}">
```

I am confused why one works not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the first case you should always use ng-href instead of href. In the second case it looks like you are programmatically submitting your form. Where is the data-url attribute used? The id should be appended to the url in the controller function that handles the form submission.

Comment: The data-url is part of some custom jQuery code that the API guy did. The whole site is Angular except that part is some special upload code he implemented, all based on jQuery and I have no leeway to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough this works for me: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dq52eM2xol7uMRkE635y?p=preview)

In HTML:

```
<input type="file" data-url="https://domain.com:9999/{{sidebar.id}}"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.sidebar = {
  id : 'a'
};
```

Are you sure this is available on scope?

Comment: It is, cause if I actually stick the {{sidebar.id}} outside of that tag, it displays the correct value on the page.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the whole url on the scope? I'm not suggesting that is the correct way to fix, but it might help you work out where the problem is.